# How can we automate the conversion of SAS Code to Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sas

Is there any way in which we can automate the conversion of a SAS code to Python.

The automation process not necessarily need to be done in python with some predefined python library, it can also be in SAS.

Any link to the solution or some predefined workflow will be really helpful.

Thank you

Regards,

Mayank

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is the parsing of SAS code. Before you can convert it, you have to know what the SAS code contains. That is problematic since SAS contains lots of procs, data steps, and at least 6 meta-languages (including macros). Also, there is SAS code and EG projects. EG Projects contain SAS code but buried in XML inside of the EG project file.

Parsing SAS is key. From there, you would need to automate the conversion to a language (in this case, python). There are people who have worked on the parsing (ex. Strumenta in Italy). However, it is a complex parse and once you have it, you need to convert it to the parts of Python that mimic SAS exactly. Very difficult.

What I have found is to get a general sense for what SAS is doing via high-level parsing and then code to generate 'target shell code' that has the general steps (ex. step boundaries such as PROCs and Data Steps). From there, it is a manual, 2 screen process: source code on one screen, target on other.

Python can be a target but the world is also moving away from needing a programming language to do analysis. Why language-to-language vs language-to-UI (ex. Power BI)?

Comment: Usually I prefer to generate the requirements from the SAS code and redesign in Python. The languages are quite different and there's often more efficient ways to do things in one language compared to another. But it's definitely more work for sure.

Comment: Reeza, I agree on redesign. However, it is not always possible when you are dealing with massive volumes and a timeline. What I do see is a move to get analysts into more UI driven, easier maintenance, paradigms. I think going from SAS to any language is a mistake. Traditional SAS resides in a world where tools didn't exist to simplify BI. Now, we have tools that can do a lot. SAS works, but if you are going through the effort to convert, minimize coding for people who primarily work on the front-line of business where speed is critical.